# MySQL table cell addition

Tags: php, mysql, addition

So I have this code, that will get all the table rows

```
 $sql="SELECT score FROM bets WHERE betid='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Okay, lets say I'll get 10 rows, that match this result.

Now I want to put all 10 score numbers together, to 1 final number, in other words i want to find the total sum of the table cells 'score'

Answer (score 2):

Use SUM function

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(score) as total FROM bets WHERE betid='$id'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Comment: but how do I echo the SUM number out on the php page, then? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try below query

```
SELECT SUM(`score`) FROM bets WHERE `betid` ='$id' GROUP BY `betid`
```

Answer (score 0):

sum is one of mysql aggregate functions. This will sum up all rows and return one value,

```
 $sql="SELECT sum(score) as totalscore FROM bets WHERE betid='$id'";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result);

 echo $rows[0]['totalscore'];
```